# Multithreading Balancing?

Tags: multithreading

I have a tricky question that I'm not sure how to tackle. Lets say we have 10 jobs(N=10) and 4 workers(num_threads=4), I need to find a function that can assign start indexes for each of these workers in such a way that no worker does more or less than 2 jobs than any other worker. As a naive approach I'm using the start_index = rank * N/num_threads formula, but this produces unbalanced results (the 4th thread only has 1 job while the first 3 have 3 jobs). Any nudging in the right direction would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to keep a single/global queue of jobs-that-are-ready-to-be-performed.  Whenever a worker-thread needs something to do, it should pop the next available job out of the queue (serialize access to the queue with a mutex, of course) and execute that job.  That way the load-balancing happens automatically/naturally, regardless of how many workers or jobs there are, and regardless of how much or how little time any particular job takes to execute.

If the worker-thread tries to get a job out of the queue and the queue is empty, you can handle that either by having the worker thread exit (since there are no more jobs to do), or (if you are expecting more jobs to be added to the queue in the future), the worker-thread could then block on a condition-variable that will get signalled after a job has been added to the queue (at which point the worker-thread can try again to get a job from the queue).

Comment: thankyou for your quick answer, while this would definately be a great approach, I need a single function! int start = start_index(N,num_threads,rank);

Comment: The problem with pre-assigning jobs to workers in advance is that you don't know how long each job is going to take, so even if you assign an equal number of jobs to each worker, that doesn't mean you will have balanced the load.  You can and will end up with some workers completing their set of jobs before others.

Comment: Re, "...I need a single function!..." Sounds like an architectural problem. You have invested effort in following one path, and now you can't turn away from that early choice without giving up on your investment. It's hard to admit that you have to tear down the house because you laid a bad foundation, but sometimes there's just no other way forward.

Comment: Low key, this is for a test...I dont care specifically about the mutlithreading aspect, and it has to be a single function lol. I may have not explained it well enough though, if you all want to bother still: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64900875/proper-thread-balancing-function

Comment: P.S.; One of my favorite add-ons to Jeremy's idea (though honestly, I have never actually needed to implement it) is for each worker to periodically check to see if any of the other workers is idle. If so, the worker can split its own remaining work into two parts, submit one of those parts to the thread pool, and then finish the other part itself.